# RelativeSource in MAUI control not bound

Tags: xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm going through simple example explained in video:

https://youtu.be/5Qga2pniN78?t=961

At 16. minute (timestamp in link above), he implements the Delete Command on SwipeItem.

In my local project, everything worked so far, but Delete Command is never triggered. I checked source generators, DeleteCommand exists.

My XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="100, Auto, *"
          ColumnDefinitions=".75*, .25*"
          Padding="10"
          RowSpacing="10"
          ColumnSpacing="10">

        <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="tom.jpg"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"></Image>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter task" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}"></Entry>

        <Button Text="Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"></Button>

        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="Red"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </SwipeItem>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <Grid Padding="0,5">
                            <Frame>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="24"></Label>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

View Model:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MauiApp1.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Items = new();
            Items.Add("test");
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<string> items;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string text;

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Add()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return;
            }

            Items.Add(Text);

            Text = string.Empty;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Delete(string s)
        {
            if (Items.Contains(s))
            {
                Items.Remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is DeleteCommand not triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved,

I forgot to add `<SwipeItems>` element after `<SwipeView.RightItems>`.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT there are no other details, I missed an element. I cannot accept my own answer until 2 days since I asked.

Comment: Thank You. I made the exact same mistake, using the exact same video, oddly enough.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteCommand,
      Source={x:Reference myPage}}"
```

where `myPage` is your page's name

```
<ContentPage x:Name="myPage" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}

Your viewmodel is not part of the visual tree, so you can't bind to it with relative source anyway.

You can use your CollectionView's Binding Context and then the specific property you need:

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}}}
```